# Next.js rewriting api route does not work

Tags: next.js

I have a simple rewrite in next.config.js:

```
 beforeFiles: [
  {
   source: '/foo/bar',
   destination: '/api/foo/bar',
  }
 ]
```

navigating to /foo/bar returns a 404 while calling /api/foo/bar works, other rewrites that are not api related works also, so I don't know what is going on, thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should change your key `beforeFiles` to `afterFiles`

Rewrite your code

```
afterFiles: [
  {
   .....
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `beforeFiles` works with static routes and `afterFiles` works with dynamic routes. But instead of re-writing routes, I would suggest you to use `basePath`:

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/api',
```

And if you don't need re-writes for some routes, then you can set basePath to false:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/without-basePath',
        destination: 'https://example.com',
        basePath: false,
      },
    ];
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that you need to include rewrites of api routes to `afterFiles` so

```
 afterFiles: [
  {
   source: '/foo/bar',
   destination: '/api/foo/bar',
  }
 ]
```

just works, although I don't know why exactly